# Uninstall openJDK 12

Tags: windows-10, java, uninstall, openjdk

I need to replace JDK 12 with JDK 8. However, I cannot figure out how to uninstall it. I searched a lot through the internet and everywhere they recommend just to use the common uninstall via *apps*. But JDK12 is not listed there. There was listed *java 8* but it was the JRE. Also, for the installation, it is recommended to add JAVA_HOME variable and add Path to the bin/. As the JDK wasn't installed by me I wasn't sure it was done. So I did this procedure, but the JDK still isn't listed in the apps but available form the command line.

*Windows 10*

```
java -version

 openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Adopt

 OpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Adopt

 OpenJDK (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Originally, the question came from the another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856943/after-installing-jdk-unable-to-run-jar/57857038?noredirect=1#comment102164461_57857038).

UPDATE *11.09.2019*:
Here are the newest screenshots. @Tiago Carneiro: where can I find the

> Java Mission Control app

?

[java in not listed in the apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZD3Q.png)
[installation folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mjGW.png)
[JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9o4l.png)
[PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSwn7.png)

Comment: Please update your  question with a screenshot that indicates that OpenJDK is not displayed in a filtered results for Add/Remove Programs.  This information is vital to answering your question properly.

Comment: Hi, AdoptOpenJDK, when installed, doesn't have "java" in its name. That's why Windows won't find it in the installed applications.

Answer (score 1):

**OS-50101**, I would recommend you to first look for the Java Mission Control app on your computer, from there you will be able to easily enable and disable the different jre's and jdk's, to manually uninstall it, even though it's not recommended, I would literally go to the **JDK12** folder and delete it.

You could then go to **Edit the system environment variables** under your Control Panel and if the **JAVA_HOME** is defined, you can edit it and change it to the path for the **JDK8**.

Also, if not already present, check your **PATH** variable and make sure that the reference to the **%JAVA_HOME%\bin;** is also there. Once that's done, a quick restart of the **cmd**, should give you a different result using **java -v**